# Stripping Data From a String In Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm pulling the hostnames from all computers in an AD domain and the current command formats it in url form with the hostname at the end. I just need the hostnames so I'd like to strip everything to the left of the last forward slash.

`(([adsi]"WinNT://$((Get-WMIObject Win32_ComputerSystem).Domain)").Children).Where({$_.schemaclassname -eq 'computer'}) | %{ $_.Path }`

It's outputting as it should, I just happen to just need the hostname, so instead of `WinNT://subdomain.somedomain.local/hostname` I just got `hostname` which I would then redirect to an output file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just posting another option, and something else that may be useful. You can also split strings by their last index, which is the last time a character appears in it. From there you can use the Substring method to select the remainder of the string.

```bsh
$lio = "WinNT://subdomain.somedomain.local/hostname".LastIndexOf('/')
"WinNT://subdomain.somedomain.local/hostname".Substring($lin + 1) # +1 to not include the slash
```

You can see all the methods for a string [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string?view=netframework-4.8)

For things like this, I would also suggest looking at the [ActiveDirectory module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/?view=win10-ps). You can run Get-ADComputer and select specific fields really easily.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `-Split` operator to help retrieve the data:

```
"WinNT://subdomain.somedomain.local/hostname" -Split "/" | Select-Object -Last 1
```

`-Split "/"` separates the value into an array of substrings using `/` as a delimiter. You can access the resulting parts using array indexes or `Select-Object`. Since you want the last value, you could alternatively access `[-1]` index of the resulting array (`("WinNT://subdomain.somedomain.local/hostname" -Split "/")[-1]`).

See [About Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_split?view=powershell-6) for more information and examples.